# D3 area chart with React Hook

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I have developed a D3 area chart with React Hooks. I need to use the same chart component with different data and gradient colors. The same page should show these two charts. The component changes the data but the colors are not changed. Can any one help me to solve this issue? Thanks!

Can download the coding files using the following link:

https://gist.github.com/chularansi/42bbab4820a0545d92bc55983228b634

[Can see two graphs with different data but the same colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J7e8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that both gradients have the same id `"#gradient"`, so both charts are modifying and using the same `<linearGradient/>` element.

One fix is to have an id in the react component and attach it to the `<linearGradient/>` id:

```js
    const Individuals = ({
      width,
      data,
      header,
      color1,
      id = Math.random().toString()
    }) => { 
      ...

      svg
      .append("linearGradient")
      .attr("id", "gradient-"+id)
      ...
     }
```

Now, each component has its own gradient. Then, move the `fill` attribute from the CSS to D3, to have access to the id:

```js
    svg
      .selectAll(".area")
      .data([data]).join("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", myArea)
        .attr('fill', `url(#gradient-${id})`)
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, You are so excellent. You solved my question that I struggle with for a few days. Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, Can you do me another favor? I need to add rounded corners to the edges of the graph. How to add rounded corners to the 'Path'? Thanks!